# Redirect proxy_fcgi php error output to browser page (apache2, fpm)

Tags: php, parsing, apache2, fastcgi, fpm

I'm on a server with apache2.4, php7.2, mysql (on linuxmint)..
I enabled the proxy_fcgi module and php-fpm to enable the http2 protocol.

Everything is working fine, but I am kind of bugged by the fact that now, php parsing errors are just outputted on the apache error log (of the virtual host).

For example if I omit a semicolon at the end of a line with a define() function somewhere in the php file before a new define().., I get that error in the log:

```
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 16261:tid 140594642073344] [client 127.0.0.1:36542] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'define' (T_STRING) in /var/vhosts/localhost/index.php on line 12\n'.
```

Which is fine, but in the browser I get no error at all, I just have a 500 Internal server status blank page.

Before setting up the proxy I used to get the php parsing errors displayed in the browser, which is much easier to debug, it's annoying to keep the error log open to check whatever small parsing error I might have.

Please don't try to get me to install an IDE editor, or use "php -l filename.php". I simply want the errors back in the browser output.

I have all the settings properly defined in all php.ini files, display_errors On, error_reporting E_ALL. It's all working fine since it's outputted to the error log :)

What I'd like to know is how to setup fpm/fcgi to stop outputting a 500 error page in the browser and actually re-forward the php errors straight in the browser as a 200 page, how it was before installing this proxy..

In the specific example, I would like to have `"PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'define' (T_STRING) in /var/vhosts/localhost/index.php on line 12\n'"` on the browser output again :)